# Node.js asynchronous multiple queries

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

so I'm trying to fetch queries with a forEach statement on a list given by the client.

After fetching the results are pushed into an array so I can retrieve the results to the client (obviously after formatting them).

The problem is that I have multiple asynchronous queries going on with mysql and I'm not quite sure how to fix them.

```
var select = function(list, flag, callback){
list.forEach(function(element){
    if (flag && (element != '')){
        connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {throw err;}
            callback(result);
        });
    } else if (element != ''){
        connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {throw err;}
            callback(result);
        });
    }
});
};
```

I call this function using the following post resolve method

```
var results = [];
if (req.body.ip == undefined){
    mysql.select(req.body.field1.split('\r\n'), false, function(result){
        results.push(result);
    });
} else if (req.body.name == undefined){
    mysql.select(req.body.field2.split('\r\n'), true, function(result){
        results.push(result);
    });
}
res.send(results);
```

I've tried working with promises but I couldn't figure a proper way to structure it since I've never used them before.

If anyone could lend me a hand I'd really appreciate it!

EDIT: FIXED IT!!!!! I used this.

```
enter code herevar select = function(list, flag, callback){
var promises = [];
list.forEach(function(element){
    if (flag && (element != '')){
        promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {reject(err);}
                resolve(callback(result));
            });
        }));
    } else if (element != ''){
        promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {reject(err);}
                resolve(callback(result));
            });
        }));
    }
});
return promises;
};
```

And then the main code like this

```
var results = [];
if (req.body.ip == undefined){
    Promise.all(mysql.select(req.body.field1.split('\r\n'), false, function(result){
        results.push(result);
    })).then(function(){
        res.send(results)
    });
} else if (req.body.name == undefined){
    Promise.all(mysql.select(req.body.field2.split('\r\n'), true, function(result){
        results.push(result);
    })).then(function(){
        res.send(results)
    });
}
```

Comment: `I've tried working with promises` - show what you've tried. Promises, and especially `Promise.all` is probably what you will need

Comment: I tried making the function a promise, but I don't know how they work exactly, but it returns the same as not having them, apparently the function can finish executing before the queries are ready.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use async functions. First, let's `promisify` your callback returning function:

```
const util = require("util");
connection.queryAsync = util.promisify(connection.query);
```

Now, let's `map` the list into continuations so we know when they're done - a promise is just something that is a value+time and you can access the value with then:

Now, in your actual code mark the function as `async` so if it was `function foo` it needs to be `async function foo` and then we can use async-await easily:

```
async function select(list, flag) {
  const relevant = list.filter(x => x != "")
  const ps = flag ? list.map(x => connection.queryAsync(x.a)) 
                  : list.map(x => connection.queryAsync(x.b)); // or whatever
  return await Promise.all(ps);
};
```

Then, on the outside

```
select([...], ...).then(() => console.log("All done!"));
```

Note: the real solution to your issue is likely solved on the SQL side - this needs to be a single query rather than N queries which will likely run much faster.